# обход блокировки при парсинге на Python

Tags: python

Добрый день Уважаемые форумчане!!! Возникла такая проблема, написал парсер, парсер собирал ссылки.

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def handle():
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) 
         Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0','accept': '*/*'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    link = []
    for i in range(0,2000):
        url = f'https://www.marathonbet.ru/su/betting/Football+-+11?interval=H24={i}'
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        cotent = soup.find_all('a', class_='member-link')
        cotent = cotent[::2]
        for i in cotent:
            link.append(f"https://www.marathonbet.ru{i.get('href')}
```

Три месяца работал как часы, без перебоев, запускался всегда в одно это же время, ну два дня назад дал сбой. Проверил верстку на сайте, не чего не изменилось, попробовал через selenium и вот что обнаружил!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сначало идет проверка браузера, а потом уже секунд через 5-7 загружается нужная мне страница, как мне решить данную проблему, очень благодарень за помощь!!!

Comment: Защита от ботов от CloudFlare. Если я не ошибаюсь вроде есть библиотека по обходу CloudFlare

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/  https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape сам не юзал, не было необходимости